# JS native function not defined

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have an Wordpress elementor website, and I've installed Google Tag Manager on it.

On my GTM there's a tag with this JavaScript:

```
  var form = getElementsByName('field[2]');

  var form1 = form[0];
  var form2 = form[1];

  var att = document.createAttribute('value');
  att.value = 'img-1';
  form1.setAttributeNode(att);
  form2.setAttributeNode(att);
```

As you can see, It's supposed to define the "value" of two form fields. The tag is firing, but the forms aren't receiving the value. When I open the console on the dev tools, I see the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementsByName is not defined at <anonymous>:1:11
```

My question is: How can a native JS function such as getElementsByName() be not defined? How can I fix this? Is it possible that the problem is with Wordpress instead of GTM?

Comment: I have to mention that editing DOM from GTM is a mistake and has to be avoided. Even though GTM lets you do that, it's not meant for it and should never be used for it.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName()` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_is_NodeList_not_an_Array.3F), so you have to access it by an index: `document.getElementsByName('field')[2]` (depending on how many of these you have).

Comment: That's not the problem. But I realized now that my problem was that I used `getElementsByName()` instead of `document.getElementsByName()`

Comment: yeah, i shared a whole generic line of code so that you can check with your use-case what's wrong in it! Glad that it helped :) @GustavoAraújo